# I want to insert a column inside a list of lists, the new column would be the 0th column python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x, insert, nested-lists

Given:

```
rowTitle = ['Time','Conditions','Temperture (C)','Feels Like (C)','Wind (Km//h','Precipitation','Rain','Snow','Ice','Sky','UV Index','Cloud Cover','Humidity','Dew Point']

data = [['10pm', '11pm', '12am', '1am', '2am', '3am', '4am', '5am'], ['Cloudy', 'Snow', 'Snow', 'Cloudy', 'Snow', 'Flurries', 'Snow', 'Cloudy'], ['-1°', '-1°', '-1°', '-1°', '-1°', '-1°', '-2°', '-1°'], ['-7°', '-9°', '-10°', '-10°', '-11°', '-11°', '-13°', '-11°'], ['18 N', '20 N', '24 N', '26 N', '30 NNW', '32 NNW', '33 NNW', '35 NNW'], ['10pm', '11pm', '12am', '1am', '2am', '3am', '4am', '5am'], ['0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'], ['49%', '61%', '61%', '49%', '58%', '51%', '57%', '43%'], ['0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'], ['10pm', '11pm', '12am', '1am', '2am', '3am', '4am', '5am'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['98%', '97%', '97%', '97%', '97%', '96%', '96%', '96%'], ['82%', '80%', '80%', '79%', '79%', '78%', '82%', '79%'], ['-3°', '-4°', '-4°', '-4°', '-4°', '-4°', '-4°', '-4°']]
```

I want to add the list rowTitle into the List of Lists data. But the "row titles" should appear in the first (leftmost) column.

I tried using insert method in python to insert the column inside data[x][0] but its not working..

```
for i in data:
    print(data.insert([i][0], rowTitle[i]))
```

This seems logical to me.. but i think I must be wrong.. other posts on here suggest Numpy as the way to do this.

Ultimately I will be making this into an HTML table to email myself, so I'd like the rows labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Ohmygod.. Pandas made it so easy!!!

All I had to do was write one line of code.

```
s = pd.Series(data, index = rowTitle)
```

and I got:

```
Time                    [6pm, 7pm, 8pm, 9pm, 10pm, 11pm, 12am, 1am]
Conditions        [Mostly Sunny, Mostly Sunny, Mostly Clear, Mos...
Temperture (C)               [1°, 0°, -1°, -1°, -2°, -2°, -2°, -2°]
Feels Like (C)           [-7°, -8°, -9°, -9°, -10°, -10°, -9°, -9°]
Wind (Km//h       [28 N, 28 NNW, 28 NNW, 26 NNW, 24 NNW, 22 NNW,...
Precipitation           [6pm, 7pm, 8pm, 9pm, 10pm, 11pm, 12am, 1am]
Rain                               [0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%]
Snow                               [0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%]
Ice                                [0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%, 0%]
Sky                     [6pm, 7pm, 8pm, 9pm, 10pm, 11pm, 12am, 1am]
UV Index                                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Cloud Cover                   [19%, 17%, 16%, 14%, 10%, 6%, 2%, 2%]
Humidity                   [62%, 66%, 74%, 77%, 80%, 81%, 80%, 81%]
Dew Point                  [-6°, -5°, -5°, -5°, -5°, -5°, -5°, -5°]
dtype: object
```

Oh man.. I spent 6 hours the other night trying to figure out a nested for loop that would do this.

Now I just need to figure out how to put this all into HTML Table and email it to myself everyday. Cool!